# Mobaxterm vs vim text copy

Tags: ssh, copy, vim, clipboard

Can I  somehow copy text between two vim sessions in 2 different terminals?
I use mobaxterm and can not scroll while marking text that I want to copy.

How can I do it? Edit 2 files on 2 different terminals (SSH sessions) with multiexec option and copy more text than I can see on terminal. I can not highlight it in any vim mode to copy it to my laptop notepad or other terminal SSH session window.

Comment: When copying more than screenheight, I usually use `cat` and select the content there...

Comment: This is, in fact, kind of solution :) but maybe someone can let us know if there is any better way to do it, i tried also other vim modes but i could not select text:)

Answer (score 0):

In vim, you can use the `r` command to read a file or command from somewhere else. So, what I would do in this scenario is:

1. Dump what you want to copy to a file, either by redirecting the output of a command, or it's already a file so just save it.
2. Open vim in the other terminal and go to the file you want to paste into
3. Use `:tabe` from command mode to open a new tab
4. Use `:r /path/to/file` to read the content of that file that you created in (1) into the buffer
5. Then use yank/paste as normal, or use ctrl-V in command mode to do a visual select block and yank that.

Note you can pass a command to `:r` as well, but you have to escape some characters, so `:r! date +\%s` will get the current unix time and insert it into the file.

Lots more tips on the well known [Grok Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1220118/216695) post.

You can also do things like turn on line numbering with `:set number`, and then read specific lines from a file: `:r! sed -n 147,227p /path/to/foo/foo.c`

Or, use the line numbering with relative numbering (`:set relativenumber`) to show you easily how many lines to yank with `y`. That way you just do `37y` and then `p` where you want it.